# running _search commands in the php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

now there is another problem that I am facing: When I run

```
$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/sample/new/_search?pretty=true' -d '{ fields:"price_incl_tax","product_id"],query:{range:{price_incl_tax:{gte:1000,lte:1500}}} }'
```

in the cygwin , it works and gives the right result. 
But when I open the link 
`"http://localhost:9200/sample/new/_search?pretty=true -d ' { fields:["price_incl_tax","product_id"],query:{range:{price_incl_tax:{gte:1000,lte:1500}}} }'"`
in the browser, I am getting the wrong answer. I am getting `20(everything) results` whereas I should get `only 2`. What to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I actually want to get the results using PHP command and I am unable to get it. I am using these functions:
 `function call`($path, $http = array()){
    if (!$this->index) throw new Exception('$this->index needs a value');
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($this->server . '/' . $this->index . '/' . $path, NULL, stream_context_create(array('http' => $http))));
  }

  `function nice_format`($type, $q){
   return $this->call($type . '/_search?' . http_build_query(array('pretty' => "true -d ".$q)));
  }

Comment: I got the answer....instead of the second function I should be using this:

  function `nice_format`($type, $q){
    return $this->call($type . '/_search?pretty=true', array('method' => 'GET', 'content' => $q));;
  }

Comment: It might be helpful for other users if you reformulated your question as a PHP question, answered it and accepted the answer. Answering your own questions and accepting the answer helps because it saves time for other users. They no longer have to read through your entire question just to realize that it's already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer....instead of the second function I should be using this: 
`function nice_format($type, $q){ return $this->call($type . '/_search?pretty=true', array('method' => 'GET', 'content' => $q));; }`